# Little NLP request on Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nlp

we are trying to find if tweets are positive or negative
We have in our database two collections : the first one regroup a list of words and if they are positive or negative
The second one is a list of tweets

Our request is :

```
t.aggregate([{$project:{wordt:{$split:["$text"," "]}}},
{$lookup:{from:"infi",localField:"wordt",foreignField:"word",as:"test_word"}},
{$project:
    {tpositif:
        {$cond:[{$eq:["$test_word.polarity","positive"]},1,0]},

    tnegatif:
        {$cond:[{$eq:["$test_word.polarity","negative"]},1,0]}}},

{$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        count_pos:{$sum:"$tpositif"},
        count_neg:{$sum:"$tnegatif"}
        }])
```

t is the tweet collection and inf the word collection.

We cant understand why it's always counting 0.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the structure of the two collections. It would help be able to run the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing `"$test_word.polarity"` but the `test_word` is an array.

You can solve it by unwinding the lookup, which splits out the "joined" rows to their own top-level rows. This shouldn't be a problem for you as you should only have one sentiment record per word (else you'd get duplicates).

```
t.aggregate([{$project:{wordt:{$split:["$text"," "]}}},
{$lookup: 
{from:"infi",localField:"wordt",foreignField:"word",as:"test_word"}},
{$unwind:"$test_word"},
{$project:
    {tpositif:
        {$cond:[{$eq:["$test_word.polarity","positive"]},1,0]},

    tnegatif:
        {$cond:[{$eq:["$test_word.polarity","negative"]},1,0]}}},

{$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        count_pos:{$sum:"$tpositif"},
        count_neg:{$sum:"$tnegatif"}
        }])
```

A good way to diagnose aggregate queries is to chop the pipeline back to the beginning clause and see if the intermediate document collections are what you were expecting. Then add the clauses back one by one.

e.g. Cutting it back to two clauses reveals the problem:

```
> db.tweets.aggregate([ {$project:{wordt:{$split:["$text"," "]}}}, {$lookup:{from:"infi",localField:"wordt",foreignField:"word",as:"test_word"}},  ]);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c59442c365f7243b44062f8"), "wordt" : [ "test", "1" ], "test_word" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c594473365f7243b44062f9"), "word" : "test", "polarity" : "negative" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c59463fd56fd34fcc370c74"), "wordt" : [ "the", "infinite", "fool" ], "test_word" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c594625d56fd34fcc370c73"), "word" : "fool", "polarity" : "positive" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c594657d56fd34fcc370c75"), "wordt" : [ "test", "the", "infinite", "fool" ], "test_word" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5c594473365f7243b44062f9"), "word" : "test", "polarity" : "negative" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5c594625d56fd34fcc370c73"), "word" : "fool", "polarity" : "positive" } ] }
```

You can see here that `"test_word" : [ { "_id" ...` is an array, by the square bracket. So the `polarity` property is in the first element of the array, not under the `$test_word` itself.

BTW. I first thought you might be able to dereference the first array element this in the `$eq` like `"$test_word[0].polarity"` but it doesn't seem to work (I thought I'd done it once).

Comment: Wow thank's a lot Scipilot, we see our problem.
Thank's again for your time and your explanation.
And sorry for the time of answer, i don't understand why i just receive the notification.